# CakePHP Creole Markup

Tags: php, cakephp, creole

I'm looking to implement http://ask.cakephp.org/markup/display/wiki and http://www.wikicreole.org/ into a CakePHP application to make it easier for users to write posts.

I have looked at the website but not entirely sure how to use it. Has anyone used Creole before and knows how to implement it into a CakePHP app?

Answer (score 0):

if you are not aware of how to use vendors in cakephp follow this http://lemoncake.wordpress.com/2007/08/08/vendors-in-cakephp/ and than go to this link http://simplewiki.org/module and download the module and put it in the vendors folders and use it accordingly in your cake app i think it would be helpful

Comment: That article has no content and neither does the one it links to as the original post! Any chance you could post how to do it if you know?